# Convert Month to Quarter in R

Tags: r, time

How to add a column using mutate to convert the month to the quarter in this case?

```
Month   Year    Michigan.OnPk   PX_LAST
  01    2012    29.64900    2.707800
  02    2012    30.91400    2.525950
  03    2012    29.60727    2.295591
  04    2012    31.63800    2.048200
  05    2012    35.39682    2.493409
  06    2012    37.37286    2.498238
  07    2012    55.50667    2.963190
  08    2012    37.62304    2.807435
  09    2012    31.29000    2.917737
  10    2012    33.77455    3.490818
  11    2012    36.42619    3.687333
  12    2012    32.87300    3.444150
```

Structure of the dataframe:

```
str(Mich)
'data.frame':   39 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Month        : chr  "01" "02" "03" "04" ...
 $ Year         : chr  "2012" "2012" "2012" "2012" ...
 $ Michigan.OnPk: num  29.6 30.9 29.6 31.6 35.4 ...
 $ PX_LAST      : num  2.71 2.53 2.3 2.05 2.49 ...
```

Comment: Or `cumsum(as.numeric(Mich$Month) %% 3 == 1)`

Answer (score 5):

The easy way would be to do the following

```
Mich$Quarter <- ceiling(as.numeric(Mich$Month) / 3)
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
Mich <- Mich %>% mutate(Quarter = ceiling(as.numeric(Mich$Month) / 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use `quarter` function from `lubridate` library:

```
lubridate::quarter(Mich$Month) -> Mich$Quarter
```